# How to get data from session object with Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I expected this code to return a string, but I'm getting an object back. This is the code:

```
var user = Data.get('session').then(function (results) {
  console.log(results.name);
  return results.name;
});
```

The console.log inside will show "brian" as expected, but a console.log of the variable user in the code above will give this object http://puu.sh/jIdeS/3444ec2041.png

If I console.log(user.$$state) it only shows the nested object with the property 'value' in it.

What can I do to return the value that I'm expecting?

**Edit:** To fix this issue I put the outside code inside the code posted here. It was pointed out that what I was attempting to do, isn't possible.

Comment: You can't. then() returns a **promise** of user name. You can't transform an asynchronous call. That's impossible.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for pointing that out. I thought that might be the case, but wanted to make sure. I was able to fix the issue by adding the outside code inside of the code above. Everything is working great now. I appreciate your response!